# Using sed, delete everything between two characters

Tags: sed

How can I delete symbols, whitespaces, characters, words everything between two characters in a line?

My 5-line file is:

```
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath.1)" 120.94.30.12 264 556 -    
"Skype for Macintosh" 120.94.30.9 1038 482 -
-129.94.30.4 217 309 -
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath.1)" 120.94.30.8 1197 747 -
"¢¢HttpClient" 120.94.30.12 594 231 -
```

I want to delete everything comes in between `"` and `"` (including the `"` characters) so that the required output should be:

```
120.94.30.12 264 556 -
120.94.30.9 1038 482 -
-120.94.30.4 217 309 -
120.94.30.8 1197 747 -
120.94.30.12 594 231 -
```

Answer (score 5):

You mean like this?

```
sed 's/"[^"]*"//' file
```

Comment: This is a good solution since it will only delete everything between the *first* pair of quotation marks on a line.

Comment: the above command works properly for test log file (few lines). But it doesn't work for big file (containing 1.5 million lines) especially for lines include:                                       "Skype 4.1" 129.94.30.9 286.

Comment: Seems to me both of these solutions should work on your Skype line. Can you tell what is different about those lines?

Comment: Add 'g' to match all pairs, which is helpful for removing html tags, for example:  sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' file

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo '"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath.1)" 120.94.30.12 264 556 -' |\
 sed -e 's/".*"\(.*\)/\1/g'
```

Comment: this command works properly for test log file (few lines). But it doesn't work for big file (containing 1.5 million lines) especially for lines include: "Skype 4.1" 129.94.30.9 286.

Comment: @HassanHABIBI What's the full line including "Skype 4.1" 129.94.30.9 286?