# Remove colon between values in array bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have file:

```
name name1 name2 name3 name4 name[n]
value1 A:A B:B C:C D:D E:E
value2 A:A B:B C:C D:D E:E
value[n] A:A B:B C:C D:D E:E
```

And I need an output

```
 name name1 name2 name3 name4 name[n]
 value1 AA BB CC DD EE
 value2 AA BB CC DD EE
 value[n] AA BB CC DD EE
```

Just simply remove colon between values. I would try something like:

```
awk '{split($2,arr1,/:/); print arr1[1]arr1[2]}' file
```

which gives me just column $2. I do not need awk solution.

Comment: `sed 's/://g' file`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using sed, delete everything between two characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096469/using-sed-delete-everything-between-two-characters)

Comment: @julien-lopez: I would consider this a non-duplicate (cf. my suggested answer) which does neither target *everything* nor *between*, thus simple translate/delete operation. At least in the given sample input - which should be representative - there is no notion but *between values*.

Comment: @Dilettant You're right, but I still vote as duplicate because the other problem includes this one, and because the op or any beginner in shell might delete more than they needed/wanted using an answer that will delete every colon. This question is very close too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187054/sed-delete-characters-between-two-strings

Comment: Are the leading spaces in the expected output an error or do you want those as well?

Comment: Sorry leading spacing is error.. I wan only remove colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question was to only remove character colon (:), thus avoiding complexity not requested for me leads to:

```
cat file_with_colons | tr -d ':'
```

or as @andlrc pointed out in comment of course (if no other process/pipe wanted):

```
tr -d ':' < file_with_colons
```

From man page on my system:

```
TR(1)                     BSD General Commands Manual                        TR(1)

NAME
     tr -- translate characters

SYNOPSIS
     tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2
     tr [-Ccu] -d string1
     tr [-Ccu] -s string1
     tr [-Ccu] -ds string1 string2

DESCRIPTION
     The tr utility copies the standard input to the standard output with substitution or deletion of selected characters.

     The following options are available:

# ... 8< - -   
     -d      Delete characters in string1 from the input.
# - - >8 ...
```

Comment: Or `tr -d ':' < file_with_colons`

Comment: UUOC is one of the warnings that the poster doesn't know shell very well so treat any post containing it with a large grain of salt. `tr -d ':' < file_with_colons` IS the right solution though.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use sed.

```
sed 's/\([A-Z]\):\([A-Z]\)/\1\2/g' file
```

- `\(pattern\)` capturing group which captures all the chars matched by the pattern. So the first capturing group `\([A-Z]\)` captures the uppercase letter exists before `:` likewise the second group captures the following letter.
- `\1` backreference to the first capturing group..

Comment: Thank you for answer. It is possible to more explain command above?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{gsub(/:/,"")}1' file

name name1 name2 name3 name4 name[n]
value1 AA BB CC DD EE
value2 AA BB CC DD EE
value[n] AA BB CC DD EE
```